# Adding an adaptive card to bot framework with python

Tags: python, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am playing a little bit with the samples of the bot framework in python from here https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python
Now I want to add a simple adaptive card to the response which I believe it is the part where it says await context.send_activity(response) but I can not attach the card. I grabbed the card from the docs sample:

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Publish Adaptive Card schema",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "size": "medium"
            },
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "auto",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Image",
                                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
                                "size": "small",
                                "style": "person"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                                "weight": "bolder",
                                "wrap": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "spacing": "none",
                                "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z, SHORT)}}",
                                "isSubtle": true,
                                "wrap": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Now that we have defined the main rules and features of the format, we need to produce a schema and publish it to GitHub. The schema will be the starting point of our reference documentation.",
                "wrap": true
            },
            {
                "type": "FactSet",
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "title": "Board:",
                        "value": "Adaptive Card"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "List:",
                        "value": "Backlog"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Assigned to:",
                        "value": "Matt Hidinger"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Due date:",
                        "value": "Not set"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Set due date",
        "card": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Date",
                    "id": "dueDate"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Comment",
        "card": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "placeholder": "Enter your comment"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]}
```

I can not find a way to attach the card to the python response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the [`Attachment`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-schema/botbuilder/schema/attachment.py) for the activity that is sent to the user:

```
ADAPTIVE_CARD_ATTACHMENT = Attachment(content_type='application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
                                      content=ADAPTIVE_CARD)
```

After this, you can attach it to your response activity like this:

```
response.attachments = [ADAPTIVE_CARD_ATTACHMENT]
```

Or you could add it when you create the response:

```
response = Activity(type='message', attachments=[ADAPTIVE_CARD_ATTACHMENT])
```

Note: I left out the additional code needed to create a valid activity for brevity, you still need to add the fields such as `channel_id`, `recipient` and `from_property`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely. Just for curiosity do you know any resources that may be of help for bot framework development on python? :D

Comment: At the moment there aren't resources for developing with v4 botbuilder-python; but you can questions here or if you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)/[wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/wiki) you'll be able to find the concepts that are being translated across languages. This should be able to at least help you get started :)

Comment: Your attachment link was broken.